# get status of last modification time of a file in linux

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the status whether the file is modified or not in Linux. I am using this piece of code and it works well, but it has a problem that it exit after the first "if" statement.

It does not look for elif statement. I am trying to get "warning" if the file is not modified from the last 2 minutes,  and it should give me "critical" if it still does not modified for 4 minutes. it always show warning or OK but does not take into account the elif statement.
 the code i am using

```
#!/bin/bash
# How to execute ./sensor.sh tem_sensor
HOUR=$(date +%H)
MIN=$(date +%M)

# Directory where they are sensor directorys
DIR=/home/robbin/Desktop/sensor_collection/
# Name of selected sensor
SENSOR=$1
# Name of sensor's directoris
SENSORS=(sensor1)

# Loop in every folder
for i in ${SENSORS[@]}
do
        # We only want the specified sensor so we will skip until we found it
        if [[ $SENSOR != $i ]]; then continue ; fi
        # You take the hour and minute value from last file
        LHOUR=$(ls -lrt $DIR/$i| tail -n1 | awk '{ print $8}' | awk -F ':' '{ print $1}')
        LMIN=$(ls -lrt $DIR/$i | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $8}' | awk -F ':' '{ print $2}')
        # We calculate the diferences
        let FHOUR=$(( HOUR - LHOUR ))
        let FMIN=$(( MIN - LMIN ))

        # if the diference is greater than 2
        if ([ $FMIN -gt 02 ] && [ $FMIN -lt 04 ]); then
            echo "WARNING - More than 2 minutes without recieving data"
            exit 1 # We put warning!
        # Else if it is not more than 2
        # We check if we have an hour of diference!
        elif [[ $FMIN -gt 04 ]]; then
            echo "CRITICAL - More than 4 minutes without recieving data"
            exit 2 # We put Red alert!
        else
            echo "OK - We recieve data"
            exit 0 # Green alert if we dont have problems
        fi
done
echo "UNKNOW - Sensor not found"
exit 3
```

If someone help me to solve this problem. cox it seems that it has no problem and it should work expectedly. I am new to bash scripts. I would be grateful. .

Comment: Have to be careful between 8am and 10am: `08` and `09` are invalid octal numbers: `HOUR=15; LHOUR=08; FHOUR=$((HOUR-LHOUR))` throws an error. You might want to explicitly use base 10: `FHOUR=$(( 10#$HOUR - 10#$LHOUR ))`. Also `date +%k` (or `+%_H`) returns the hour without the leading zero.

Comment: Similarly, use `%_M` instead of `%M` to avoid invalid octal minutes 08 and 09, 18 and 19, etc

Comment: is there are reason you're not using the stock `check_file_age` plugin?

Comment: @Keith I don't know about check_file_age. I am new to bash and programming

Comment: @glennjackman I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can re-arrange your if-else statements as follows:

```
if [[ $FMIN -gt 04 ]]; then
    echo "CRITICAL - More than 4 minutes without recieving data"
    exit 2 # We put Red alert!
elif [[ $FMIN -gt 02 ]]; then
    echo "WARNING - More than 2 minutes without recieving data"
    exit 1 # We put warning!
else
    echo "OK - We recieve data"
    exit 0 # Green alert if we dont have problems
fi
```

This is simpler to read and should do what you want.

Comment: i will give it a try and will come back soon

Comment: it still does not enter into critical state. .don't know why. it shows only warning.

Comment: are you sure `FMIN` got to 5?

Comment: @chicks yes i am sure. it goes until 10

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the conditions in the if and elif clauses.  The first condition matches both cases, so the second one is never getting checked.